# rte_keepalive_register_relay_callback confusion

Tags: dpdk

The [documentation](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__keepalive_8h.html#a1db760eacc4e6d07780fb9360b868853) for `rte_keepalive_register_relay_callback()` mentions that this function "is called when a core is known to be alive". At the same time, however, the function has a parameter `callback` that is "called upon detection of a dead core." I am confused then. Is `rte_keepalive_register_relay_callback()` called when a core is detected to be alive or dead? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The documentation for rte_keepalive_register_relay_callback() mentions that this function "is called when a core is known to be alive".

Not `rte_keepalive_register_relay_callback()` function, but the `callback` we pass to this function.

> At the same time, however, the function has a parameter callback that is "called upon detection of a dead core." I am confused then.

That is another function, `rte_keepalive_create()`. The callback we pass there will be called upon dead core detection.

> Please explain.

There might be two cases: 1) the core is dead or 2) the core is alive.

1. The callback we pass to `rte_keepalive_create()` is called when the core is dead.
2. The callback we pass to `rte_keepalive_register_relay_callback()` is called when the core alive.